# Sum multiple Python Pandas columns, with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am summing up multiple columns (W1,W2,W3,L1,L2,L3),with a condition on the 'Best of' column like this. It works, but seems a little long winded. Is there a way to make the sum more succinct?

```
print(
(
my_data[my_data['Best of']==3]['W1'].sum()+
my_data[my_data['Best of']==3]['W2'].sum()+
my_data[my_data['Best of']==3]['W3'].sum()+
my_data[my_data['Best of']==3]['L1'].sum()+
my_data[my_data['Best of']==3]['L2'].sum()+
my_data[my_data['Best of']==3]['L3'].sum())/len(my_data[my_data['Best of'].between(3, 3, inclusive=True)])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

create a mask for the condition and a list of columns, then use `sum` and `mean`.

```
m = my_data['Best of']==3

cols = ['W1','W2','W3','L1','L2','L3']

print( my_data.loc[m, cols].sum().mean() )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. It was very useful.